# Does zero variance imply constant random variable?

Tags: probability

I've read similar posts, but I didn't understand if that is indeed true. For some continuous random variable $X$:

$$E\left[\left(X-E\left[X\right]\right)^{2}\right]=0\implies P\left(\left(X-E\left[X\right]\right)^{2}\neq0\right)=0\implies\left(X-E\left[X\right]\right)^{2}=0\text{ a.s.}$$

so $$E[X] = X\text{ a.s.}$$

But does that imply $X=const$?

Comment: I found this, it oughta help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228624/random-variable-with-zero-variance

Comment: It implies that $X$ is equal to a constant almost surely i.e. with probability $1$. That constant happens to be $E[X]$.